# Starting numbered lists at 8 (or any number) instead of 1

Tags: support, markdown

The way the formatting works, even if I put in a comment like this:

> "8. The system of claim 1..."

it appears like this:

> 1. The system of claim 1...

It would appear that numbered lists always start at 1, even if the underlying text is some other number. This is inconvenient for this site because often times we'll want to refer to claim numbers out of order. Does anyone know of a way to override the default numbering?

Comment: See also [Numbering/bullet interpretation bug?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35181) and [Can't start a numbered list on a number other than 1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137077) on the main Stack Exchange meta site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are triggering the automatic numbering for bulleted lists, as such:

From [Markdown Editing Help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help):

```
A numbered <ol> list:

1. Numbered lists are easy
2. Markdown keeps track of the numbers for you
7. So this will be item 3.
```

As a workaround type a backslash before the dot:

```
364\. This won't become a list.
```

Since this isn't actually a list anymore, you'll have to keep the lines from getting scrunched up into one paragraph. Just add two spaces after each item to force the linefeed.

8. Item A   <--- There are two spaces at the end here
7. Item B
6. Item C
etc.